# Como publicar um projeto Angular CLI (Angular 4) no meu servidor?

Tags: angular, build

Estou aprendendo Angular CLI e consegui fazer uma aplicação rodar a aplicação em `localhost` do ng serve. Porém, queria colocar essa aplicação no meu site hospedado na `Hostinger`, apenas para testar e etc.

Então, fui jogar todos os arquivos (26 mil arquivos) da aplicação no site por casa do "node_modules".

Pesquisando vi que tinha que fazer o "ng build". Fiz o "ng build", ele criou a pasta "dist", fui jogar essa pasta no site, ele subiu tudo certinho, mas não executa os componentes, fica apenas no `index.html`.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para colocar essa aplicação no meu site?

index.html (Dentro da pasta "dist"):
    "
    
    
      
      Angular Reddit

```
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.css">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Carregando...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>"
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angularreddit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

inline.bundle.js:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
/******/    var parentJsonpFunction = window["webpackJsonp"];
/******/    window["webpackJsonp"] = function webpackJsonpCallback(chunkIds, moreModules, executeModules) {
/******/        // add "moreModules" to the modules object,
/******/        // then flag all "chunkIds" as loaded and fire callback
/******/        var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, resolves = [], result;
/******/        for(;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
/******/            chunkId = chunkIds[i];
/******/            if(installedChunks[chunkId])
/******/                resolves.push(installedChunks[chunkId][0]);
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
/******/        }
/******/        for(moduleId in moreModules) {
/******/            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moreModules, moduleId)) {
/******/                modules[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/        if(parentJsonpFunction) parentJsonpFunction(chunkIds, moreModules, executeModules);
/******/        while(resolves.length)
/******/            resolves.shift()();
/******/        if(executeModules) {
/******/            for(i=0; i < executeModules.length; i++) {
/******/                result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = executeModules[i]);
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/        return result;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // objects to store loaded and loading chunks
/******/    var installedChunks = {
/******/        4: 0
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    // This file contains only the entry chunk.
/******/    // The chunk loading function for additional chunks
/******/    __webpack_require__.e = function requireEnsure(chunkId) {
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] === 0)
/******/            return Promise.resolve();
/******/
/******/        // an Promise means "currently loading".
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId]) {
/******/            return installedChunks[chunkId][2];
/******/        }
/******/        // start chunk loading
/******/        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
/******/        var script = document.createElement('script');
/******/        script.type = 'text/javascript';
/******/        script.charset = 'utf-8';
/******/        script.async = true;
/******/        script.timeout = 120000;
/******/
/******/        if (__webpack_require__.nc) {
/******/            script.setAttribute("nonce", __webpack_require__.nc);
/******/        }
/******/        script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + ".chunk.js";
/******/        var timeout = setTimeout(onScriptComplete, 120000);
/******/        script.onerror = script.onload = onScriptComplete;
/******/        function onScriptComplete() {
/******/            // avoid mem leaks in IE.
/******/            script.onerror = script.onload = null;
/******/            clearTimeout(timeout);
/******/            var chunk = installedChunks[chunkId];
/******/            if(chunk !== 0) {
/******/                if(chunk) chunk[1](new Error('Loading chunk ' + chunkId + ' failed.'));
/******/                installedChunks[chunkId] = undefined;
/******/            }
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = [resolve, reject];
/******/        });
/******/        installedChunks[chunkId][2] = promise;
/******/
/******/        head.appendChild(script);
/******/        return promise;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // on error function for async loading
/******/    __webpack_require__.oe = function(err) { console.error(err); throw err; };
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([]);
//# sourceMappingURL=inline.bundle.js.map
```

Comment: Está usando o plano VPS?

Comment: Daniel, não! Estou usando o plano gratuito da Hostinger!

Comment: Então é isso - você precisa de um servidor linux que você possa controlar, configurar, instalar módulos, etc. Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://www.hostinger.com.br/hospedagem-web) e você vai ver que o suporte do plano gratuito é pra PHP e não o que você está usando... :p

Comment: O que eu faria: primeiro arrumar um servidor que dê acesso a um prompt de comando do linux, depois eu usaria o [git](https://git-scm.com/) e um serviço como [esse](https://bitbucket.org/product) para salvar meu projeto inteiro. Depois no servidor linux, eu simplesmente daria o comando 'pull' do meu projeto inteiro, e depois 'npm install' - e tudo deveria estar rodando! Sugiro que você pesquise esses comandos e principalmente o 'git' (já tem bastante pergunta de como utilizar ele aqui, e o próprio serviço que eu indiquei te ajuda a fazer o básico, e é grátis).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas e pela resposta, Daniel! Eu vou procurar saber melhor sobre os comandos e provável que vou comprar um VPS. Tenho alguns projetos em PHP para clientes, creio que vai ser melhor hospedar tudo em um lugar só e eu mesmo gerenciar. Novamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu escrevi errado, o comando completo que 'baixa' seu projeto pro servidor é 'git pull' - boa sorte! :)

Comment: @DanielGomes eu não recomendaria, em *nenhuma* circunstância, o desenvolvimento no host de produção. O processo inicial do Nicolas está correto - desenvolvimento local e publicação da versão de distribuição.

Comment: @NícolasAigner você poderia postar aqui o conteúdo de `dist\index.html`? E, se possível, o seu `package.json` também?

Comment: @OnoSendai nem eu, +1

Comment: @OnoSendai, posto sim! Coloquei na pergunta os arquivos!

Comment: Perfeito - e como estão os conteúdos de `inline.bundle.js` e `main.bundle.js`? Estes são os arquivos responsáveis por carregar tanto as dependências quanto a sua aplicação. Eles estão corretamente populados?

Comment: @OnoSendai, consegui colocar o inline.bundle.js, o outro arquivo está gigante, mas está correto também. Creio que seja o que o Daniel Gomes falou, por não ser um VPS e etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como você descobriu é necessário fazer um build da aplicação, ao fazer isso os arquivos gerados podem ser utilizados em qualquer servidor web.

Ex: no wampserve você pode copiar a pasta `/dist` do seu projeto angular para a pasta `/www` do wampserve e acessar `localhost/dist` e lá estará sua pagina em angular 4.

No seu caso você deve "subir" sua aplicação para a hospedagem da hostinger e configurar seu htaccess para redirecionar todas as requisições para o arquivo index.html, só dessa forma o angular poderá ter controle sobre as rotas.

adicione um arquivo .htaccess na pasta da sua hospedagem com essa regra abaixo para fazer essa configuração

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

      RewriteRule ^(.*) /dist/index.html [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Obs: coloque no seu servidor somente os arquivos da pasta **dist**, os arquivos gerados devem ser usados em conjunto e não separadamente pois um depende do outro para funcionar.

ps: eu também uso a hospedagem da hostinger para testar minhas aplicações em angular e para trabalhar com o angular só é preciso de um servidor de conteúdo estático e nada mais.

Comment: Rodrigo, boa noite! Obrigado por responder tão bem minha dúvida.
Consegui fazer o Angular funcionar no Wamp graças as tuas dicas. 
Porém, joguei a pasta dist para o servidor e não funcionou. Creio que não vai funcionar com o plano gratuito e também não existe mais o .htaccess, tentei criar um, mas não funcionou, quando vai para lá, em 5 minutos ele é apagado. Eu vou comprar amanhã um mês do VPS da Hostinger para fazer alguns testes, se tudo der certo, beleza! Se não der, paciência! Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularHelloWord</title>
  <base href="/">
```

Retire a tag base do index, para que seus arquivos js sejam direcionados corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, pra mim funcionou fazendo o build assim:

```
    ng build --base-href /nomeDoSeuProjeto/
```

Depois só fazer o upload do projeto que está dentro da pasta dist/ para o servidor.

Fonte: https://angular.io/cli/build