# Como fazer uma implantação de um aplicativo Angular no Heroku usando o Gitlab?

Tags: node.js, angular, deploy, heroku, gitlab

Uso Angular 5 (5.2.10) e o Angular CLI (1.7.4) e gostaria de fazer o Deploy no Heroku, porém meus arquivos estão no repositório do Gitlab. Mais algumas informações: node (8.11.1) e npm (5.6.0).

Comment: Talvez [este link](https://medium.com/letsboot/angular-continuous-delivery-deployment-with-gitlab-ci-stage-on-commit-and-prod-on-git-tag-151ce3c74619) ajude mano, da uma olhada...

Answer (score 1):

O Heroku suporta [*deploy* com Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) de forma nativa, basta acrescentar um novo *remote* ao repositório para o Heroku e fazer *push* para esse *remote*.

Eu tentei fazer [algo semelhante](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git) com a minha Azure Web App - uma SPA em Angular - e a entrave que encontrei é não poder fazer *push* direto do repositório do projeto Angular porque o Angular é transpilado para JavaScript no ato de *build*. Como tal tem duas opções:

1. Criar um novo repositório na pasta de *output* da transpilação (normalmente `../dir_do_projeto/dist`) com o Heroku como *remote* - o que é fácil dar problemas por causa de ter um repositório dentro de outro repositório;
2. Criar um novo repositório local no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento com o Heroku como *remote* para onde copia manualmente os ficheiros da `dist` sempre que quiser fazer *deploy*.

Pessoalmente optaria pela 2ª opção uma vez que encontrei problemas com a anterior. Qualquer das formas tenho bastantes colegas que preferem a 1ª opção pela simplicidade e não precisar da interação manual deles.

---

**Recursos úteis:**

- [O que é Transpilação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189894/o-que-%C3%A9-transpila%C3%A7%C3%A3o/189903#189903)
- [O que é SPA e no que se diferencia de uma página não SPA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212952/o-que-%C3%A9-spa-e-no-que-se-diferencia-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-n%C3%A3o-spa)
- [Como publicar um projeto Angular CLI (Angular 4) no meu servidor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207059/como-publicar-um-projeto-angular-cli-angular-4-no-meu-servidor)

Comment: Por enquanto valeu, vou dar uma "estudada", são muitos termos técnicos em poucas linhas. Não sei do que se trata uma SPA, na pasta de *output* da transpilação e etc.

Comment: @RafaelSouzaCalearo Acabei de editar a resposta com alguns recursos que explicam essas questões. Deia uma vista de olhos!

Comment: Ok, vou olhar e fico muito agradecido pela compreensão e ajuda! Só mais um detalhe, meu projeto está no repositório do Gitlab, não preciso fazer nenhuma configuração local e/ou remota (Gitlab/Heroku)? Por que tenho a mesmo aplicação no Github e lá tive que fazer algumas modificações (tbm no Heroku) aí sim consegui publicar no Heroku. Ou seja, só com um Deploy nativo do Git conseguirei e mais essas explicações que me passastes? Desculpa a minha ignorância.

Comment: Eu nunca utilizei o Heroku pelo que não consigo perceber de que está a falar... Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Minha pergunta foi se eu terei que configurar algo no Heroku ou Gitlab pra fazer desse jeito que tu colocou, porque outrora eu usei o Github e tive que fazer configurações no meu Heroku e aplicação (criei novos arquivos, instalei dependências e etc.). Mas ta tranquilo estou fazendo (lendo) o que tu colocou como resposta!

Comment: Em princípio não, o que provavelmente terá de fazer será configurar o Heroku para suportar os deploys via Git, o que está explicado num dos recursos da resposta acima. É apenas uma questão de configurar o `remote` no seu repositório local e sempre que quiser atualizar o projeto no Heroku, além de fazer push para o GitLab, fazer push para o Heroku.